# Invalid API call from Angular - placeholder in remoteServiceBaseUrl

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

ABP package version: 5.9.0
Base framework: .NET Core

Using the .NET core with Angular template.

I configured appConfig.json as below to identify tenant using subdomain.

```
{
  "remoteServiceBaseUrl": "http://{TENANCY_NAME}.localhost:21021",
  "appBaseUrl": "http://{TENANCY_NAME}.localhost:4200",
  "localeMappings": [
    { "from": "pt-BR", "to": "pt" },
    { "from": "zh-CN", "to": "zh" },
    { "from": "he-IL", "to": "he" }
  ]
}
```

But the Angular template makes the API call to the URL `http://%7Btenancy_name%7D.localhost:21021/AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution.  Update `app-initializer.ts` as follows:

First, add method

```
private replaceTenantPlaceholder(baseUrl: string, defaultSubDomain: string): string {

    const tenancyNamePlaceHolder = '{TENANCY_NAME}';
    baseUrl = baseUrl.replace(tenancyNamePlaceHolder + '.', tenancyNamePlaceHolder);
    
    var subDomain = window.location.hostname.split(".")[0];
    subDomain = subDomain.replace(`$:{window.location.port}`, "");
    
    switch (window.location.hostname.split(".").length) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            //No sub-domain on current url
            subDomain = defaultSubDomain;
            if (subDomain.length > 0) subDomain += ".";
            break;

        case 3:
            //Use the current url's sub-domain
            subDomain += ".";

        default:
    }
    
    return baseUrl.replace(tenancyNamePlaceHolder, subDomain);
}
```

Then update method `getApplicationConfig`:

```
AppConsts.appBaseUrl = this.replaceTenantPlaceholder(response.appBaseUrl, "www");
AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl = this.replaceTenantPlaceholder(response.remoteServiceBaseUrl, "");
```

No other modifications needed for this part of the multi-tenancy.  Make sure you update your `Configuration.Modules.AbpWebCommon().MultiTenancy.DomainFormat` in your CoreModule and define your CorsOrigins in `appsettings.json`

My client application requires "www" in the domain, so that is why I have the defaultSubDomain parameter.  You can omit that if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Disclaimer: Not tested, minor changes may be required.*</sub>

From Issue #5800<sup>1</sup> in the ASP.NET Boilerplate GitHub repo:

> You need to extract it from the URL and replace the URL by yourself.

Steps:

1. Implement `RemoteServiceBaseUrlService` similar to `AppUrlService`<sup>2</sup> in the template.

```ts
export class RemoteServiceBaseUrlService {

    static tenancyNamePlaceHolder = '{TENANCY_NAME}';

    ...

    get remoteServiceBaseUrl(): string {
        if (this._appSessionService.tenant) {
            return this.getRemoteServiceBaseUrlOfTenant(this._appSessionService.tenant.tenancyName);
        } else {
            return this.getRemoteServiceBaseUrlOfTenant(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returning url ends with '/'.
     */
    getRemoteServiceBaseUrlOfTenant(tenancyName?: string): string {
        // let baseUrl = this.ensureEndsWith(AppConsts.appBaseUrl, '/');
        let baseUrl = this.ensureEndsWith(AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl, '/');

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

2. Replace `API_BASE_URL` provider in `RootModule`.

```ts
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    // { provide: API_BASE_URL, useFactory: () => AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl },
    {
      provide: API_BASE_URL,
      useFactory: (remoteServiceBaseUrlService: RemoteServiceBaseUrlService) => remoteServiceBaseUrlService.remoteServiceBaseUrl,
      deps: [RemoteServiceBaseUrlService],
      multi: true,
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class RootModule {}
```

3. Accept `remoteServiceBaseUrl` in `SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.initSignalR`.

```ts
export class SignalRAspNetCoreHelper {
    // static initSignalR(callback?: () => void): void {
    static initSignalR(remoteServiceBaseUrl: string, callback?: () => void): void {
        const encryptedAuthToken = new UtilsService().getCookieValue(AppConsts.authorization.encryptedAuthTokenName);

        abp.signalr = {
            autoConnect: true,
            connect: undefined,
            hubs: undefined,
            qs: AppConsts.authorization.encryptedAuthTokenName + '=' + encodeURIComponent(encryptedAuthToken),
            // remoteServiceBaseUrl: AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl,
            remoteServiceBaseUrl,
            startConnection: undefined,
            url: '/signalr'
        };
```

4. Inject `RemoteServiceBaseUrlService` in `AppComponent` and pass `remoteServiceBaseUrl`.

```ts
export class AppComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
  sidebarExpanded: boolean;

  constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private _layoutStore: LayoutStoreService,
    private _remoteServiceBaseUrlService: RemoteServiceBaseUrlService
  ) {
    super(injector);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'sidebar-mini');

    // SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.initSignalR();
    SignalRAspNetCoreHelper.initSignalR(this._remoteServiceBaseUrlService.remoteServiceBaseUrl);
```

5. Replace any remaining usage of `AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl` similar to steps 3 and 4.

## References

1. Issue #5800: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5800
2. `AppUrlService`: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/d2a2ab3ff4486983c84aa48a173c2de102f36c2e/angular/src/shared/nav/app-url.service.ts